# How to connect two nodes on two different networks

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I'm trying to create my own chain so I have a VM which is the main node that will mine all the time, so that I don't lose the chain if all the nodes are off. I want also to make my friends able to mine and send transactions on this chain, but the problem appears when I try add a new node using `admin.addPeer()` and this node is on a different network from the VM network. I am able to connect two nodes if they are on the same network but I'm not able to connect two different nodes if they are on different networks.
How can I achieve that?
I think my problem is when I make  the full URL using the enode, because I'm using the IP address of the node which is an internal IP, how can I make a full URL using external and internal IP address. Also, I don't have any access to the router, so I cannot configure it.

Comment: The VMs need access to each other through an IP address. If that's not possible (due to a NAT for example) then I don't think you can link them.

Comment: I cannot even connect two nodes which are running on two different computers and they are connected in two different networks. I'm only able to connect these two nodes if they are connecting to the same network.

Comment: If the nodes cannot talk to each other then you will not be able to sync them. In your case a vpn might be a solution.

Comment: I'm using a VPN to connect to the VM, but I'm not able to connect the node which is stored on my computer with the node which is stored on the VM.

Comment: After `admin.addPeer()`, can you see the new node if you list them with `admin.peers`? If you just add a peer, `admin.addPeer()` will not give you an error if it's unreachable at the moment.

Comment: I deployed a private network for prototyping purposes last autumn https://github.com/Gelassen/swap, although all nodes are within the same local network. I have plans to scale up to new nodes from external network in production, so I might face with this issue too. In case you had solved your issues, please share your results as a answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

When you first start up geth, you will see on the right on some line `enode://[whatever]`.
Copy paste the enode with the enode part down to the ip. Now replace the local ip with your external ip, then go to your other node and in the JS console, type `admin.addPeer("[the enode with the externalip]")`.

Please delete the `[` and `]`.

They now should be connected

Comment: I put the external IP but they didn't connect to each other, I think the external IP is not enough, there should be something else to distinguish the machine on the network, like port. However, I open the port using the command --port and I used a distinguish port but it didn't work also, it seems that I should configure the port on the router. Anyway, I don't have access to the router's settings.